# Is there a sandbox feature in Git, which let's you save the entire state of your repo to play around safely?

Tags: git

So, you are at a point where you know you need to do some cleanup in your git repo, potentially using rebase or other stuff that could make it really messy to undo if you do it wrong.

Is there a way to tell Git *"save this state of the entire local git repo, so that I can rollback everything to this point, in case things go wrong?"*
Something like a "sandbox mode", which lets you play around with your repo safely, performing potentialy disasterous operations, without the risk of messing anything up.

I'm not talking about adding a tag or something to a specific point in history, but about something that would reset all the changes made in the git repo on all branches from that particular state in time. The potential to roll back *everything* (all the git history/state). Something similar to the OSX Time Machine.

*Update 2019-02-19: I should clarify that by "potentially disasterous operations", I don't mean to the code itself, but actually messing around with the repo structure in git, using for instance `git reset --hard` or similar commands.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you search for is the `git worktree` command:

Also see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree:

> A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time. With git worktree add a new working tree is associated with the repository. This new working tree is called a "linked working tree" as opposed to the "main working tree" prepared by git-init or git-clone. A repository has one main working tree (if it’s not a bare repository) and zero or more linked working trees. When you are done with a linked working tree, remove it with git worktree remove.

Comment: Yes! https://opensource.com/article/21/4/git-worktree Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The Git repository itself is a sandbox.

Clone your repository and play in the cloned repo. You can do anything in it, you can even completely destroy it (remove it). As long as you don't `git push`, the original remains untouched.

If you want to start over just remove the clone and re-create it again. Or run:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The `checkout` command makes `master` the current branch on the local repo. The `reset` command restores the local current branch and the working tree to the state of branch `master` on the `origin` remote (assuming you started playing on the `master` branch).

Comment: Thanks. The last commands there though assume you've just made changes on the master branch. It will not also simultaneously reset all the other branches you might have made changes to. So it won't "reset the entire repo". Removing the clone and recreating the repo again, will do the job though, like you said.

Answer (score 4):

You can just copy your folder with Git repository somewhere else and do anything you want there (assuming only local operations). This will not affect your original local repo and if you want to discard changes in your copy - just remove it and copy again.

Comment: Additionally, it is very hard to make something in Git that is not easily reversible. There are very little commands that are undoable like a `git clean -fdx` or `git checkout .` where you might loose unversioned changes. Everything that is already committed or stashed is relatively save unless you do stuff that makes commits unreferenced and they are garbage collected, but as the reflog is there for (by default) 30 days, you really have to want to loose those commits during that period to have something inundoable.

Comment: What would you do if you then wanted to keep the changes you made in the copy, without having to redo them in the original repo? Would you delete the original repo, and use the copy instead? Would that pose a risk of loosing some reference/link to the remote repo, or are the git remotes and all such refs also copied into the repo copy?

Comment: Git remotes are copied as well. You can either switch and proceed in the copy or push to remote from the copy and then get back to original repo and pull changes from remote.

Comment: I think this answer is not really useful: you don't need to clone your sandbox to play around. None of your commits will get deleted, unless they've been orphaned for a while. Definitely not while you're "messing around" in it

Answer (score 2):

Git tries very hard to not lose or corrupt data and already provides tools to help you recover work. 
Its [basic build blocks](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/) are persistent immutable data structures.

For example, instead of rebasing branch `foo` directly, create a new branch named `foo/rebase` where `foo` currently is, check it out and rebase `foo/rebase` instead. You will see that none of the commits reachable from `foo` will be modified, so you are safe to work on the new branch. Just like a transaction, you can rollback the work (simply remove `foo/rebase`) or commit that operation (make `foo` points to `foo/rebase` with `reset --hard`, or maybe merge).

In any case, you still have the [reflog](https://fr.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog/) which keeps references to objects not currently reachable by any branch or tag.
You could also clone your repository, but this is a bit overkill in most situations.
In your case it seems that you are going to change branches in mass, so I must admit that cloning the repository might be the best approach.

Comment: The tip of using a designated rebase branch was enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr : It can be done, it's git's standard behaviour;

I know that this question has been resolved, but I do feel the urge to clarify the situation to provide a higher level of intuition about how git works.

What @Magne is looking for is already how git works by default:

**every commit you make is your safe point, and nothing you do can make it go away**  (... with a few exceptions..)

Git keeps every commit you make, as long as it can find it by browsing back the tree of commits, starting from the tip of the existing branches and tags, and moving back from parent commit to parent commit.

If you are on commit A, and you rebase it onto a different branch, your new commit A' (it's a different one from A because it has different parents) will be where your HEAD is moved to, which means that you'll keep working on that one as you keep committing.

What happened to commit A ? **It's still there** !    (for limited time only, while supplies last). 
It's just that there is no branch or label that can reach it anymore. But if you remember the commit hash, you can still check it out.  If you don't remember the hash, `git reflog` will show you all commits that you visited, and therefore that hash will be right there in that history, and you'll be able to recognize it from the commit message at least.

Because that old commit A is unreachable from any branch or label, git will eventually get rid of it after some configurable amount of time, once it decides to re-compact its internal storage.

**AS LONG AS YOU LABEL YOUR COMMIT, IT WON'T BE ERASED**. So... rebase at will, if you have any doubts after you rebased, go back with `git reflog` and label the old `commit A` so that you can always go back to it.

And if you decide that you didn't like that rebase after all, you `git checkout` that old commit, you move the tip of your branch to it by force (`git branch -f <branch-name> <commit-that-will-be-tip-of-branch>`) and then checkout that branch (`git checkout <branch-name>`).

This is a bit hard to follow without a good graph. 
I definitely encourage the reader to go play with this "git simulator" : http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/
It really helps at visualizing what's going on.

Comment: What are the exceptions you mentioned? What if I want to test out 'performing potentially disasterous operations' like a hard git reset?

Comment: I have to admit that there are hardly any exceptions. The only case I can think of is for someone to to a git reset, git rebase or force move a branch, which would leave some commits orphaned, which would then be deleted by git while doing its automatic cleanups before you have a chance to realize that you wanted to undo everything

It's a very contrived example, but it *could* happen.

Comment: Also, let me point out that a `git reset --hard` is still not going to delete any commits. The only danger there is that you will lose uncommitted changes in your sandbox. That's why `git reset --hard` is dangerous: you lose uncommitted work.     But again.... if you commit it, it's there to stay

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But what if it is the restructuring of your repo that you want to test out? Actually doing rebases, resets, moving branches, etc. It could get hard to find each and every commit and recreate the structure you started with, couldn't it?

Comment: it helps to visualize with http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/ .  If you rebase, you are creating new commits, while the old ones are still there and they are still linked to each other. moving branches, simply means moving a "special label" from one commit to another. It's a lot less work than you think. I wish I could just show it on a whiteboard...

Comment: Thanks, that's very a very helpful link and insight!

Comment: happy to help !  Also if you can upvote my answer other people might notice it too ...  ;)